# How to Add API Key to Usage Plan in AWS API Getaway

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a problem with creating **API Key** associated with an **Usage Plan** in AWS API Getaway (using AWS SDK for node.js).

In AWS Console you can attach API Key to Usage Plan via this button:
[image]

However I could not find a similar function in [AWS SDK documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This code do the magic:

```
var params = {
  keyId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  keyType: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  usagePlanId: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
apigateway.createUsagePlanKey(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

What I was missing was that keyType must be **"API_KEY"**

Comment: This one requires that you first create an API key with some other API call, then obtain the key id and now make this call to bind it to a usage plan. A more Seamless programming technique would be to do all these in one API call. Maybe the ImportApiKeyCommand gets that done.

Answer (score 2):

This is a full example of creating an API Key and assigning it to a usage plan.

```
async function createApiKey(apikey_name, usage_plan="free") {

    const usage_plans = {
        free: "kotc0f", // usage plan IDs
        basic: "ju5fea"
    };

    if (!usage_plan || !(usage_plan in usage_plans)) {
        console.log(usage_plan + " usage plan does not exist");
        return false;
    }

    var params = {
        name: apikey_name,
        description: "Created via API on " + (new Date).toISOString(),
        enabled: true,
        generateDistinctId: true
    };
    
    let api_key = await new Promise((resolve) => { 
        apigateway.createApiKey(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("ERROR", err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                resolve(false);
            }
            else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });

    if (!api_key) return false;

    params = {
        keyId: api_key.id,
        keyType: "API_KEY",
        usagePlanId: usage_plans[usage_plan]
    };

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        apigateway.createUsagePlanKey(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                resolve(false);
            }
            else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });

    return api_key;
}
```